# HIGHCHARTS: Event on Export can't access x-axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I am using the render event to alter the positioning of of my x-axis labels on a highchart. It works great - centering labels between ticks on a datetime x-axis and removing the last label.

When I export the chart - with the same setup - the function is called (see centerTimelineLabels below), but it cannot access the rendered x-axis labels. *Please see the images below showing the different x-axis labels in the DOM and as an exported PNG.*

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/SirMunchington/36xcbr7m/52/

Specifically, `this.container` inside of the function, is an empty wrapper on export... no children.

**Is there a way to access and manipulate the x-axis labels in a highchart when exporting?**

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
      chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        events: {
          render: centerTimelineLabels
        }
      }
    },
   ...
```

```
var centerTimelineLabels = function() {
  var labels = $('.highcharts-xaxis-labels span', this.container).sort(function(a, b) {
    return +parseInt($(a).css('left')) - +parseInt($(b).css('left'));
  });

  $(labels).css('margin-left', 
    (parseInt($(labels.get(1)).css('left')) - (parseInt($(labels.get(0)).css('left')) + parseInt($(labels.get(1)).width()))) / 2
  );

  $(labels.get(this.xAxis[0].tickPositions.length - 1)).remove();
};
```

**CORRECT X-AXIS VIA WEB**
[image]

**INCORRECT X-AXIS VIA EXPORT**
[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I added a link to a jsfiddle above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the demo.

Try to use this config - notice that the render event triggers after each chart redraw:

```
"events": {
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
      ticks = xAxis.ticks,
      firstTick = ticks[xAxis.tickPositions[0]],
      secondTick = ticks[xAxis.tickPositions[1]],
      ticksDistance = secondTick.mark.getBBox().x - firstTick.mark.getBBox().x;

    for (let i in ticks) {
      let tick = ticks[i];
      if (!tick.isLast) {
        tick.label.translate(ticksDistance / 2, 0)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o06r1yfw/

To hide the last label set the `xAxis.showLastLabel` property to false.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.showLastLabel

Comment: Thank you, works great! I noticed the solution also required removing  "useHTML": true  and "align": "left" under the xAxis labels settings.

Comment: with this same chart I need it to make the x-axis labels auto-rotate instead of truncate when the chart resizes to a more narrow width.